# Docker - connect to mysql with sequel pro

Tags: mysql, sequelpro, laradock

I know this question has been asked before, but i have tried so many things that i really think i lost what is right or not, so to be quick, when i do **docker ps** on my terminal, i have the mysql image:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                        NAMES
d7111485360b        laradock_mysql       "docker-entrypoint.s…"   19 hours ago        Up 27 minutes       0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp, 33060/tcp            laradock_mysql_1
```

**So in my sequel pro i think i have to do this:**

```
Host: 127.0.0.1
(i also tried 0.0.0.0 ; domain.test:8080 ; and mysql) 
User: root
Pass: root
Port: 3306
```

To access the website i´m in port 8080. I really don´t know what i am suppose to do, i´m new at docker, and after this, i´m installing a adminlte template on my laravel project which comes with the authentication and so...it needs database.

Any ideas? regards

**EDIT**

Has alec pointed out, i should go to my **my.cnf** inside laradock/mysql/ and the result i have is:

```
# The MySQL  Client configuration file.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

[mysql]

[mysqld]
default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
sql-mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
character-set-server=utf8
```

Comment: We need to know a) how you started the container (docker run command, or docker-compose.yaml .. paste both); b) the outputs of `docker inspect <container>`

Comment: I started the container like this: docker-compose up -d mysql. Regarding the docker inspect i can see a lot of info, including the gateway and ipadress, i have tried both

Comment: What is the error message when you try connect?

Comment: " Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' cannot be loaded: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/plugin/caching_sha2_password.so, 2): image not found" also i don´t know if it is important or not, but my laradock folder is NOT inside my laravel project. I have a project folder and inside there is laradock folder, project1 folder and project 2 foldder, then my nginx has two .conf and this shows and works, the connection to the database not!.